# AWS access to resources with cross account and IAC setup

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, resources, roles, amazon-iam

I have the following scenario:
We are build an infrastructure on AWS with infrastructure as code (IAC) on multiple accounts. 
I have **account A** and **account** B in the beginning, and I want to create the infrastructure in both using CloudFormation and Terraform. When account A is created, I want to allow a role in account B to have access to a S3 bucket, that is created in account A. The role in account B is not yet created, however, I do know, what the name is eventually going to be.

My question: Can I grant access to non-existing resources between both accounts, if I do know how they are going to be named eventually?
OR: Do I have to create the resources before I can grant the access?

Comment: [IAM Roles](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles.html) Have a look there, I think you can find a solution to your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Stack Sets](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/stacksets-concepts.html) would allow you to run manage stacks in multiple accounts and regions with CloudFormation. CloudFormation is pretty smart about dependencies, but you can explicitly use the [DependsOn](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-attribute-dependson.html) attribute to have resources wait for the dependent resource to be ready, like the [IAM Role for cross-account access](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/tutorial_cross-account-with-roles.html) in this case.